# Moving Floating Action Button up and down to avoid getting blocked by a snackbar

Tags: android, floating, floating-action-button

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton) to implement a floating action bar and I can't seem to find a way to move the button when a snackbar appears on screen. Is it even possible with that library?

Comment: You should go through the github issues.  I came avross this. https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton/issues/90   and this  https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton/issues/90

Comment: Awesome. I must have missed that one because I've already looked at the GH issues. Thanks! I got it working now.

Comment: Awesome.  I was thinking avout using that library.  Was it easy to fix?

Comment: Yeah, I literally followed the suggestion from the discussion you linked to. When the snackbar is shown, use `fab.animate().translationYBy(-snackbar.getHeight())` and when it's hidden, use the same thing except ommit the negative sign before `getHeight()`. This is a bit hacky because what can happen is that the user keeps pressing the button after the initial button press and the floating button keeps going up. I just used some boolean logic to mark button's current state as a workaround.

Comment: @naja can you post what you have done. How did you got snackbar instance and how did you find when it's closed and when it was open

Answer (score 51):

To anyone looking out for answer in future..

Coordinator Layout used as Parent Layout of Floating Action Button will handle the animation effect for you automatically.

The floating action button has a default behavior that detects Snackbar views being added and animates the button above the height of the Snackbar accordingly.

[Floating Action Button Behavior](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.Behavior.html)

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/clayout">
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/filter_icon"
    app:rippleColor="@color/colorGray"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then our SnackBar code would use Coordinatorlayout[here clayout] as parentlayout like below:

```
Snackbar.make(clayout, "Click on row to know more details", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                        }
                    }).show();
```

Comment: But not for custom Floating Action Buttons or menus. So the animation has to be done mannually

Comment: But, for the native FAB, this should be the simplest and accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

Try using`android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` and `CoordinatorLayout`.

And then try this:

```
fabView = findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button_id);
Snackbar.make(fabView, "Hi", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Answer (score 7):

You could switch to [android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) and use [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) to specify Behaviors for your views.

> CoordinatorLayout is a super-powered FrameLayout.
>
> CoordinatorLayout is intended for two primary use cases:
>
> 1. As a top-level application decor or chrome layout
> 2. As a container for a specific interaction with one or more child views
>
> By specifying Behaviors for child views of a CoordinatorLayout you can provide many
>   different interactions within a single parent and those views can also
>   interact with one another. View classes can specify a default behavior
>   when used as a child of a CoordinatorLayout using the DefaultBehavior
>   annotation.
>
> Behaviors may be used to implement a variety of interactions and
>   additional layout modifications ranging from sliding drawers and
>   panels to swipe-dismissable elements and buttons that stick to other
>   elements as they move and animate.
>
> Children of a CoordinatorLayout may have an anchor. This view id must
>   correspond to an arbitrary descendant of the CoordinatorLayout, but it
>   may not be the anchored child itself or a descendant of the anchored
>   child. This can be used to place floating views relative to other
>   arbitrary content panes.

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin:

```
class CustomBehavior : CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FloatingActionButton> {   

....

    override fun onAttachedToLayoutParams(params: CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) {
        super.onAttachedToLayoutParams(params)

        //set dodgeInsetEdges to BOTTOM so that we dodge any Snackbars
        params.dodgeInsetEdges = Gravity.BOTTOM
    }

.....

}
```

Comment: Or you can also use `app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom"` in the XML.

Answer (score 2):

You can Use to set parentLayout - as FAB,

```
Snackbar.make(parentLayout, R.string.snackbar_text,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction(R.string.snackbar_action, myOnClickListener).show();
```