# Move floating action button above directions popup in Google Maps API fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

I am using the Google Maps API in Android Studio (through the default Google Maps Activity). I enabled `setMyLocationEnabled(true)` but set `setMyLocationButtonEnabled` false since I wanted to add a custom Floating Action Button, which looks better to me, for moving to the current location. When a marker is clicked, the API automatically generates direction buttons at the bottom right of the maps fragment to that marker however the FAB that I've implemented covers those buttons up.

[image: FAB covers API directions]

After looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912656/moving-floating-action-button-up-and-down-to-avoid-getting-blocked-by-a-snackbar) I wrapped the maps fragment and floating action button in a `CoordinatorLayout`, hoping that it would move the FAB up when a marker is clicked, as it does with snackbars, but it doesn't. Is there a way to activate that motion manually or at least simulate it with touch events or something similar? I tried to look for ways to move the FAB at runtime (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216564/move-floating-action-button-above-keyboard)) but I was unsuccessful in finding a fitting solution for my situation.

Here is the xml for the layout for the activity, let me know if more information is needed. Thanks in advance!

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="(hidden for privacy)"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/find_my_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_my_location_gray"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose giving `android:layout_marginBottom` to your FAB from xml does not work or you don't prefer this solution, so:

You may either hide direction buttons at the bottom with [setMapToolbarEnabled()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings.html#setMapToolbarEnabled(boolean)) if you don't need them: `googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);`

or listen for marker clicks with [GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener:](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener)

`googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);`

and then do whatever you want in `onMarkerClick()`:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        //give some margin programmatically
        //return false to preserve the default behaviour, true o/w 
        return true;
}
```

Comment: While I didn't use your exact solution, the mention of `onMarkerClick` got me thinking to do something in there as you suggested. I actually had that implemented already to load up some data for each marker, so I just added `FAB.hide()` on `onMarkerClick()` and `FAB.show()` on `onMapClick()` (since one likely won't need to go back to current location with the info window up). I don't know why I didn't think of that earlier, but thank you nevertheless!